# rails json response not rendered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

The controller should show a different page depending on the button pressed using AJAX, via a POST request

```
# POST /site_device/1
def show_page
     @site_device = SiteDevice.find(params[:id])
     respond_to do |format|
         format.js
         format.json { STDERR.puts "JSON!"; render 'show_page.js.erb'  }
    end
end
```

The controller code #show page runs, and calls the json view template (below)

```
<% STDERR.puts "got_here" %>
$('#device-data').html("<h1>Foo!</h1>" ).trigger('create');
```

We know the above code is being called as the `STDERR` lines are being output on the server.

On the browser (Chrome) we can use the console to test whether the code in the view template runs correctly – and it does: Entering `$('#device-data').html("<h1>Foo!</h1>" ).trigger('create');` into the Google Chrome console results in the html being re-rendered with “Foo!” in the right place.

Here however is the perplexing bit.  The code that is being executed on the server doesn’t appear to be received at the browser, or if it is, it is not executing, or not rendering

Has anyone else had any similar problems/issues?

Comment: Can you please post your ajax function?

Comment: when you mean .trigger('create') what exactly is that doing. Meaning show us your create eventhandler

Comment: found this online - it appears to be a jquery method to force the page to refresh. Code works fine in the browser without it. I'll append the original question to remove if that will help

Answer (score 1):

To hazard a guess, if your ajax function has `dataType: 'JSON'` it will receive but not execute the response. If you set `dataType: 'script'` the response will be executed.

Please post your ajax function if this isn't the answer.

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean by "the AJAX function". What is it / where would I find it? (I'm using Agile Dev with Rails Ch 11.2 as a guide).

Comment: How does someone make this ajax request? What do they click on, and/or what script is submitting the request?

Comment: `<%= button_to device.functionality, show_page_site_device_path(id: device.id), remote: true %>`